# Symbology to layers not working

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, symbology, mxd, data-frame

I want to apply layer symbology to all TIFF in a group layer but it does not work:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mxd.activeDataFrame
groupName = "New Group Layer-s"
lyrFile = "G:\work insar\1402mehr1402\LAYER\Mahad2.lyr"
allLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, groupName, df)[0]
 for layer in allLayers:
   arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layer, lyrFile)
   layer.visible = "True"
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: In what way does your code not work?  Does it give you an error message?  If, please include that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong with your code:

1. You have used the group layer name as the wildcard parameter in `Listlayers()`. So what's the only thing in your mxd with that name... your group layer so that's what is returning a group layer.
2. You end your line with `[0]`. That is telling Python to return the first thing in the list so your next line is incorrect as `allLayers` is not a list object that you can use a for loop on.

So as it stands `allLayers` is a group layer object and not a list of layers.  You need to read the help file and understand how to step over a group layer to drill down to the layers in it. There will probably be examples if you search this forum.

Answer (score 0):

hi i do not know why but now it workes
`enter code here

```
  import arcpy

  mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

  df = mxd.activeDataFrame

  groupName = "New Group Layer-s"

  lyrFile = "mahad2.tif"

  allLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, groupName, df)[0]

    for layer in allLayers:

    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layer, lyrFile)
    layer.visible = "True"
 arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).